# Caching in Java with Singleton Pattern

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I want to send some file(s) to cache and read them from cache in Java. I've been searching for this on the internet but there are many advanced stuff for caching. I've downloaded ehcache but couldn't find a way to work things out. Is there a library for just caching and reading files from cache in java? I'm kinda new in Java, therfore I don't understand advanced stuff easily.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How you would solve this depends on what kind of environment you are implementing the application for. Is it a webapp? If so, which server are you using? Is it a desktop app? Then there is a different story. Try to me more precise in your question.

Comment: Your OS should cache the file anyway, so I think it's usually no point in caching a few files. Try doing a test... load the file twice and measure the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provide simple way to implement cache in your application.

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[Ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) is also a good one.
Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Cacheonix. Cacheonix is an open source distributed data management framework for Java. For more details on File Caching , read

http://www.cacheonix.com/articles/How_to_Cache_a_File_in_Java.htm